# How can I check the version of a .net core dll from bash within a docker container

Tags: .net, bash, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a docker container that runs a .Net Core 1.x Web API.  There is a problem with the way the service is packaged and it wont start up properly.  I'm able to shell into it via

`docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash my-image`

After running a `docker export ...` on the container I know the problem is the wrong version of Newtonsoft.Json.dll because I was able to check the version of Newtonsoft.Json.dll on Windows 10.

Is there a way that I could have checked the version of Newtonsoft.Json.dll at my bash prompt while inside my docker container?

Answer (score 0):

I see that it's been a while but this may help someone else.

I think the easiest way to check the version of a dll in a docker container is to copy it to your local and see the version from there.

You can easily copy the dll from your docker container to a local directory with

```
docker cp <container name>:<dll full path in container> <local path>
```

Comment: this may work, but more or less accomplishes the same thing I was doing in my initial question.